# Unexpected php usort result

Tags: php, arrays, compare, usort

I have an array with files. And I want to sort them by their min value (I'll explain below).

This is an example of array:

```
$files = array(
    array(
        'name' => "DevTools/tools/files/design/js/custom/http_build_query.js",
        'range' => array(
            'min' => 0
        )
    ),
    array(
        'name' => "DevTools/tools/files/design/js/custom/Form.js",
        'range' => array(
            'min' => 0
        )
    ),
    array(
        'name' => "DevTools/tools/files/design/js/custom/VanillaJS.js",
        'range' => array(
            'min' => 0
        )
    ),
    array(
        'name' => "resources/js/plugins/jquery.js"
    ),
    array(
        'name' => "resources/js/plugins/jquery-ui.js"
    ),
    array(
        'name' => "resources/js/plugins/popper.js"
    ),
    array(
        'name' => "resources/js/plugins/bootstrap-v4/index.js",
        'range' => array(
            'min' => 800
        )
    ),
    array(
        'name' => "resources/js/plugins/bootstrap-v4/util.js",
        'range' => array(
            'min' => 0
        )
    ),
    array(
        'name' => "resources/js/plugins/bootstrap-v4/dropdown.js",
        'range' => array(
            'min' => 200
        )
    ),
    array(
        'name' => "resources/js/plugins/bootstrap-v4/collapse.js",
        'range' => array(
            'min' => 0
        )
    ),
    array(
        'name' => "resources/js/custom/global.js"
    ),
    array(
        'name' => "layouts/cms/.js/+0.js",
        'range' => array(
            'min' => 0
        )
    ),
    array(
        'name' => "resources/js/plugins/module/delete.js"
    ),
    array(
        'name' => "resources/js/plugins/module/form.submit.js"
    ),
    array(
        'name' => "resources/js/plugins/module/piece.image.js"
    ),
    array(
        'name' => "resources/js/plugins/select2.js"
    )
);
```

It's easy to understand. We have names for all files. And some of them have [range][min].

What I need to do is keeping their order, but sorting **only** files from same folder which have the [range][min], so we reorder these ones by [min].

### My code

So I use this function:

```
usort($files, function (array $a, array $b) {
    if (!isset($a['range']) || !isset($b['range'])
    || dirname($a['name']) != dirname($b['name'])
    || $a['range']['min'] == $b['range']['min']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return $a['range']['min'] <=> $b['range']['min'];
});
```

Which does exactly what I said above. So only those ones are correcly reordered, as you can see here:

```
[6] => Array
    (
        [name] => resources/js/plugins/bootstrap-v4/util.js
        [range] => Array
            (
                [min] => 0
            )

    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [name] => resources/js/plugins/bootstrap-v4/collapse.js
        [range] => Array
            (
                [min] => 0
            )

    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [name] => resources/js/plugins/bootstrap-v4/dropdown.js
        [range] => Array
            (
                [min] => 200
            )

    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [name] => resources/js/plugins/bootstrap-v4/index.js
        [range] => Array
            (
                [min] => 800
            )

    )
```

Which is great.

### The problem

Now I add in my $files array this one:

```
array(
    'name' => "resources/js/plugins/module/piece.images.js"
)
```

Append it anywhere you want in $files, the usort will reorder **entire** array with no logic:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => DevTools/tools/files/design/js/custom/http_build_query.js
            [range] => Array
                (
                    [min] => 0
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => resources/js/plugins/bootstrap-v4/collapse.js
            [range] => Array
                (
                    [min] => 0
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => resources/js/plugins/select2.js
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => resources/js/plugins/module/piece.image.js
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => resources/js/plugins/module/form.submit.js
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => resources/js/plugins/module/delete.js
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [name] => layouts/cms/.js/+0.js
            [range] => Array
                (
                    [min] => 0
                )

        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [name] => resources/js/plugins/bootstrap-v4/util.js
            [range] => Array
                (
                    [min] => 0
                )

        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [name] => resources/js/custom/global.js
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [name] => resources/js/plugins/bootstrap-v4/dropdown.js
            [range] => Array
                (
                    [min] => 200
                )

        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [name] => DevTools/tools/files/design/js/custom/Form.js
            [range] => Array
                (
                    [min] => 0
                )

        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [name] => resources/js/plugins/bootstrap-v4/index.js
            [range] => Array
                (
                    [min] => 800
                )

        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [name] => resources/js/plugins/popper.js
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [name] => resources/js/plugins/jquery-ui.js
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [name] => resources/js/plugins/jquery.js
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [name] => DevTools/tools/files/design/js/custom/VanillaJS.js
            [range] => Array
                (
                    [min] => 0
                )

        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [name] => resources/js/plugins/module/piece.images.js
        )

)
```

I have no idea why is that happening. If you can find out why, can you please see if there is a solution please?

If I didn't explain well, please ask in comments for clarification.

So, what I need to do is keeping their order, but sorting **only** files from same folder which have the [range][min], so we reorder these ones by [min].

Comment: Can you please specify what is the expected output format?

Comment: @DamianDziaduch it's last array I added. Their is an array. Function usort get's array by reference and modify that reference. After that, I printed out the array in <pre> tag.

Comment: I mean the array you want to have from the usort, not the actual output from the usort. I am not sure what you want to achieve here.

Comment: The same here as in first example: "What I need to do is keeping their order, but sorting only files from same folder which have the [range][min], so we reorder these ones by [min]."

Comment: That if () statement (from closure) returns 0 (means "don't change order") if they have different dirs (OR the other rules). Does it makes sense?

Comment: I want sort, by [min], only files from same dir, which have [range][min]. As the example shows that.

Comment: Yeah, its a bit confusing. I've been trying a mix of various items there, and you are right, in that the results seem unpredictable. And then change entirely when adding just that one extra row to the array or not, changes the whole results. I can't seem to make it behave either :(

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: First, can you simplify the problem? Not for you, but for us. For demo purposes, can you make the initial array hold only 2 to 5 items and still break? Second, can you post how you are appending items to the array after the sort.

Comment: I am not appending after the sort. That's the second example where $files has a new item. After that, I sort with same function. In that situation, doesn't work properly.